# Short story with death sentences for patent infringements and a sadistic judge

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this many years ago. As far as I remember, the judge was fascinated by spiders and an AI computer did play a role as well. I think it was rather a short story and not a novel, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## ["The Venetian Court"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1875576.The_Venetian_Court) (1982) by Charles L. Harness

> The Plaintiff Universal Patents Inc. was heartless.
> The judge Rex "Spider" Speyer was merciless.
> Ellen Welles' case seemed hopeless.
> Unless her lawyer could locate the mad creator of FAUST - the robot-inventor who'd given Universal Patents its stranglehold on the world economy - she was sure to die for patent infringement a capital crime in the twenty-first century.
> Quentin Thomas Ellen's lawyer already knew that the judge was a psychopath and he quickly learned just how dirty Universal could play...

[image: The Venetian Court front cover]

---

As has been mentioned in a comment by user14111 it is possible you read the initial short story version published in [*Analog* in 1981](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49521).

---

I found this by Googling `"short story" with death sentences for patent infringements` (part of the title of the question) which turned up [this review](https://search.proquest.com/openview/939d54f0d43dc554f0e576f7afeb6dbf/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=1816914). From there I was 99% sure it was correct but I checked Goodreads and a couple of other links for the work to be sure.

Comment: Wow. That was quick. And you're totally right. Thanks a lot!

Comment: ...and it is available for purchase, too - as an ebook for 3 Euros. Just bought it.